# Determine if anonymous type's property is a generic collection

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I need a method to cycle through each object's properties and log the property name and value. On occasion, however, I hit a property that is a list object and the whole thing crashes. I've gather the condition below from various SO posts but it returns false every time. Wondering how to test if your method property is a generic collection type?

**Class Definition**

```
public class DtccProducer
{
    public string ProducerDateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string ProducerGender { get; set; }
    public string TransactionType { get; set; }
    public List<BigAddress> Addresses { get; set; }
    public List<BigCommunicationItem> Communications { get; set; }
}
```

**Method**

```
    private static void ParseProducer(object obj)
    {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        Type objType = obj.GetType();

        foreach (PropertyInfo info in objType.GetProperties())
        {
            string key = info.Name;

            Type propType = info.PropertyType;

            if (propType.IsGenericType && typeof(ICollection<>).IsAssignableFrom(propType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()))
            {
                // This condition never passes - always evaluates to false
            }
            else
            {
                string value = (string) info.GetValue(obj, null);
                _sb.AppendLine(key + ": " + value);                    
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code I use to identify lists in my log:

```
if (!propType.IsPrimitive && !propType.IsEnum && propType != typeof(string) && propType.GetInterfaces().Any(x => x.IsGenericType 
           && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>)))
```

Edit: I've added some additional checks to filter out primitive types (int's, bool's, etc.), enum's and strings.

Comment: Actually I spoke too soon. Every property passes this condition. Any idea why? Doesn't seem right to me that a string would evaluate as true here.

Comment: Adding this condition to your if statement seems to have done the trick: `&& propType.IsGenericType`

Comment: My fault. I had filtered out strings (and enums) before this if statement in my code and I missed that when copying the code. BTW, it catches strings because strings implement IEnumerable<char>.